# GitHub: Pull Requests: do I have to branch after a pull request?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-pull, pull-request

Suppose I fork a GitHub project and make some changes and then
create a pull request for the changes to be merged into the
original project I forked from.

Once I do this, if I return to my forked project and commit more
files to this forked project, then these files show up in the
pull request, which is not what I want.

So, how do I solve this issue? Do I have to branch after each
pull request to prevent further commits into the forked code
to be pulled into the original code by one of the main code
developers/maintainers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should branch *before* the pull request.

Implement each pull request (feature or fix) in its own branch, then submit a PR for the branch.

If the repo owner asks you to change something in a PR, add a commit in the PR branch.

If you want to start working on something else, no problem: you start a new branch from the master branch.

If you want your master branch to be identical to the original repo's master branch, no problem, because you haven't made any change to master. So you can simply pull the upstream master branch.

If a PR is rejected, no problem. You can simply delete the branch containing the PR. Your master hasn't been modified.